# Is there a way to resolve this error in cardinality_threshold problem?

Tags: r

I tried to use ggpairs to visualise my dataset but the error message that I am getting is what I don't understand. Can someone please help me?

```
> describe(Mydata)
         vars      n     mean       sd   median  trimmed      mad min       max     range  skew
Time            1 192008  4257.07  2589.28  4156.44  4210.33  3507.03   0   8869.91   8869.91  0.09
Source*         2 192008     9.32     5.95     8.00     8.53     2.97   1     51.00     50.00  3.39
Destination*    3 192008     8.22     6.49     7.00     7.31     2.97   1     51.00     50.00  3.07
Protocol*       4 192008    16.14     4.29    19.00    16.77     0.00   1     20.00     19.00 -1.26
Length          5 192008   166.12   464.07    74.00    96.25    11.86  60  21786.00  21726.00 14.40
Info*           6 192008 63731.70 46463.90 60732.50 62899.62 69904.59   1 131625.00 131624.00  0.14
         kurtosis     se
Time            -1.28   5.91
Source*         15.94   0.01
Destination*    13.21   0.01
Protocol*        0.66   0.01
Length         349.17   1.06
Info*           -1.47 106.04
> Mydata[,1][Mydata[,1] ==0]<-NA
> ggpairs(Mydata)
Error in stop_if_high_cardinality(data, columns, cardinality_threshold) : 
  Column 'Source' has more levels (51) than the threshold (15) allowed.
Please remove the column or increase the 'cardinality_threshold' parameter. Increasing the 
cardinality_threshold may produce long processing times
```

Answer (score 2):

As the error suggests, the way to get rid of the error is to set `cardinality_threshold=NULL` or `cardinality_threshold=51` as `Source` and `Destination` are both factor variables with 51 levels.

However, they're likely to be hard to see any detail in the plots, if it plots at all because one of the panels of the plot would be attempting to fit 51 barplots with 51 columns into it. You may want to think if grouping your factor levels makes sense for the analysis you're interested in, or exclude the factors (although that only leaves two continuous variables).

Comment: With a simulated dataset of the same structure, I was able to plot 3 columns but R became pretty unresponsive. The detail of the plot was impossible to make out though. Not part of the answer because it depends on your computer and graphics device

Comment: > ggpairs(Mydata[1:14,])
Error in stop_if_high_cardinality(data, columns, cardinality_threshold) : 
  Column 'Source' has more levels (51) than the threshold (15) allowed.
Please remove the column or increase the 'cardinality_threshold' parameter. Increasing the cardinality_threshold may produce long processing times                                                          I have reduced the rows to 14, yet the error is still coming up

Comment: Yes, you'll still need to set the `cardinality_threshold` as outlined in the error message and my answer above